# ubuntu terminal - do not keep in memory sudo password once used it the first time

Tags: passwords, sudo

how can I disactivate to keep in memory the sudo passoword once I have use it in the terminal? For example, when I type "sudo apt update" it asks me the sudo password, but then, when I type "sudo apt upgrade" it doesn't ask it. I would like to type it every time I use sudo.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set in `/etc/sudoers` line:

```
Defaults timestamp_timeout=0
```

This will totally disable caching the passwords in `sudo`